# Problem: Creating mutiple TCP-Server objects

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp

I have written an asynch TCP-Server class. Now I try to create several TCP -Server objects listening on different ports. The first server instance works well, but if I try to create the next instance the Bind of the IPEndpoint throws an 'invalid argument' exception.

I am new at the field of socket programming. Maybe I have chosen a wrong approach. My aim is to provide a TCP server or instances of servers which listening on different ports an provides different services on these ports.

Any help is welcome.

```
public class TCPServer
{
    static readonly Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    static readonly List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
    private const int bufferSize = 65000;
    static readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    ConsoleHelper ch = new ConsoleHelper();

    public void SetupServer(int port)
    {
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        socket.Bind(ep);
        socket.Listen(0);
        socket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
    }
....
```

Comment: I also have not done much with sockets, but I noticed the socket, clientSockets, and buffer are all defined as 'static'. Is this correct? My guess is that the second instance is conflicting with the first instance because they are static.

Comment: @Wiz yes, it's disastrous.  'static' misuse is far too common:(